Why am I missing error texts in my language (sr-Latn-RS; Serbian)?
Windows function FormatMessage should be able to give you the error text that corresponds to given error code in desired language, if this language is installed on the system. My Windows is initially set on en-US, and I also added keyboard for sr-Latn-RS.
I now want to read error messages in the other language. I've set my language to be the language of the OS. Still, FormatMessage returns ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Problem is, file KernelBase.dll.mui is missing from folder Windows\System32\sr-Latn-RS\. There are 839 files in this folder, but not the file that I need the most right now.
If I install another language, like de-DE then I can get error messages in German. There are 1725 files in de-DE folder. My question is what should I do to see error messages in sr-Latn-RS (Serbian)? I could've sworn I was able to have them several years ago.
Maybe there is no KernelBase.dll.mui for my language. Where can I see which languages have this file?

In good use case FormatMessage should return TRUE, and return you the text for given error code. If the function cannot do that it will return FALSE and another function GetLastError will return the error code that tells you WHY FormatMessage failed. In my case the reason for a failure is ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_FOUND. This makes sense if you coded in Windows API. If you haven't then either disregard that part, or look it up.

I feel this is more Super User question, than a Stack Overflow question, because I ask how to set up my Windows. But I gave details that are more in line with SO community. These details can be ignored.
